# How do you configure helm airflow chart when DAGs are mounted to a persistent volume?

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

The helm `stable/airflow` chart has the airflow `extraVolumeMounts` and `extraVolumes` sections and the `persistence` section in the values.yaml file. Which of those sections needs to be configured when DAGs are mounted to a persistent volume?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already sorted this out, but you may want to take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58341364/917651